# Equivalence class with disjunction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's define relation $ \mathcal R $ in $\Bbb R$ in the following way:

$ x \mathcal R y \iff (x=y \space \lor \space \exists k \in \Bbb Z (x,y \in (k,k+1))$

Describe equivalence classes.

Well, after lot of my effort i can't solve this problem. This is my thoughts

Equivalence class will look as follows (i think):

$[x] = \{ y \in \Bbb R: x \mathcal R y \}$

Im thinking now about truth this sentence : $(x=y \space \lor \space \exists k \in \Bbb Z (x,y \in (k,k+1))$

There can be three possible ways :
1) first sentence true, second also true
2) first false, second true 
3) first true, second false

Note 1. $(x=y \space \lor \space \exists k \in \Bbb Z (x,y \in (k,k+1))$
Note 2. $(x\neq y \space \lor \space \exists k \in \Bbb Z (x,y \in (k,k+1))$
Note 3. $(x=y \space \lor \space \forall k \in \Bbb Z (x,y \notin (k,k+1))$

Now i'm stuck. Propably that is not a proper way to analyse this problem and i shouldn't consider three cases here.

Well, if i'll put as class representative integers in situatuion $ x = y $ i'll get something like $[x] = \{ k \}$. When im taking other number from $\Bbb R$ set different than $\Bbb Z$ i have problems, bacause propably i have to use second sentence, i mean: If $\Bbb R-\Bbb Z $ equivalence class will look like $[x] = \{\space \exists k \in \Bbb Z  : y \in (k,k+1) \}$ .

Im struggling also with Note 2. (If it's all true, and for example i'll take $x = 0$ and $ y = 100,5 $ i can't find any integer number such that $y \in (k,k+1)$. In note 3 i have similar problems.

Please give me some hints, because i really want to finally unterstand how equivalence relation and equivalence classes works in harder problem (prop it is easy example for u).

Comment: The following are all in the same equivalence class:  $5.5, 5.1, 5.7772, 2\pi - 1, \sqrt{26},\dots$.  A completely separate equivalence class would include such things as $6.5, 6.00001, 6.99, 2\pi, \sqrt{39},\dots$.  Now... food for thought... is $6$ related to anything other than itself?  Would it be related to the first group, or would it be related to the second group?  Remember... the notation $(a,b)$ here is the interval of real numbers which are *strictly* greater than $a$ and *strictly* less than $b$, e.g. $5.5\in (5,6)$ but $5\not\in (5,6)$.

Comment: 6 is related only to itself, it can't be in group one or two, because as u mention, there is open interval. But still i have problems with note those facts in proper way :( Propably i still don't understand how disjunction works in this problem.

Comment: Imagine if you will a long line of buckets of unit width... $\dots\sqcup\!\!\sqcup\!\!\sqcup\!\!\sqcup\!\!\sqcup\dots$, lined up just below the real number line and then we turn on gravity.  Some numbers will fall into the buckets just below them.  Other numbers may get caught on the rims of the buckets.  What is special about those numbers which fell into the same bucket?  Do you see what this analogy has to do with your problem?

Comment: Well, those numbers which fell into the same bucket are in $y \in (k,k+1) $, and the numbers caught on the rims are integrals, where those numbers are not included in mention interval. So for example $ [5] = \{5\}$ and $[5.00001] = \{(5,6)\}$ right? So there is no need to check three posibilities truth sentence from right side $\iff$? And how should i iterpret this disjuntion? Just like that every equivalence class representative is the same as y on this equivalence class set so i can say that, but i have to check if $ y \in (k,k+1)$? Kk

Comment: If you insist on checking the three possibilities, you'll come to the same conclusion that I'm trying to lead you to.  Here on, the only intervals I'll be referring to are intervals of the form $(k,k+1)$ for some integer $k$.  In your first case, the numbers are equal and in the same interval (*implying they aren't integers*).  In the second case, the numbers aren't equal but are in the same interval.  In the third case, the numbers are equal but are not in the same interval (*implying they are integers*).

Comment: The list of equivalence classes would be $\dots,(-1,0),\{0\},(0,1),\{1\},(1,2),\{2\},(2,3),\dots$

Comment: "the numbers aren't equal but are in the same interval. " Can i ask you for example equalation class like this?

Comment: The numbers $5.1$ and $5.5$ are related.  This is because $5.1$ and $5.5$ fall under your second case since $5.1$ and $5.5$ aren't equal to one another but they do both lie within the same interval, $(5,6)$.  Note... this describes *merely two* out of *uncountably infinitely many* numbers in the equivalence class $(5,6)$.  The point is to recognize that *every* pair of numbers within $(5,6)$ are related, not only those that satisfy the second condition to be considered related, but also those that satisfy the first condition too.

Comment: Thank you very much for explain this problem :)